# Probability problem with average value

Tags: probability

First day of Math101 Course have average of 4% absent usually. There are 32 student assigned for Mat101 of year 2015. So teacher prepared 30 student class for first day of this year. What's the probability of every student who came in first day are able to find a seat?

Yes its not the exact question, I wouldn't want my teacher find this out, so i made it.
 What kind of method or technique i need to use to solve this problem ? 
 i have learned: 
 `Combinations,Sampling with(out) replacement,(order matter or does not), Binomial probability.partitions...`

Comment: What is the distribution of absence (normal, uniform, etc)?

Comment: Not coming, sorry for my bad english

Comment: Average of 4% students didnt show up first day

Comment: I know the definition of absence. But what is the distribution of it? The fact that the average is $4$% is simply not sufficient for answering this question.

Comment: Previous years average of absent was 4%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Normal Approximation of Binomial Distribution, we can get the probability that the number of people who will be attending must be less than or equal to  30, such that 30 seats will be occupied by the attending students and none will be left out.

Here proportion of absentees = 0.04,

proportion of attendees = .96

No of students registered = 32

Mean = np = 30.72

standard deviation = $\sqrt{npq} = \sqrt{32\times 0.04\times 0.96} = 1.108$

For all students to get a seat in the 30 seat hall, the number of attendees (X) should be less than 30.

Hence $P(X\le 30) = P(\frac{(X-Mean)}{SD}\le \frac{(30-Mean)}{SD}) = P(Z\le\left(\frac{30-30.72)}{1.108}\right)=P(Z\le-0.6498)$

$P(Z\le- 0.6498) = 0.2579$-.

That will be probability that all students who attend the class on the first day get a seat.

Comment: Square root of npq is not equal to 1.108. Did u take it appropriately?

Comment: I think it is correct.  Could you do the calculation and I don't understand where I am wrong?